# How to extract multiple words from a line using shell script

Tags: shell, command

I need to extract the name of root CN of a website stored inside a file as shown below.

```
google.com   CN=Google Internet Authority G2
youtube.com   CN=Google Internet Authority G2
```

I want to extract this portion from the line "Google Internet Authority G2" and count the occurrence in the file.

I tried using this command, but I don't know the proper regex to be used for it. Can somebody help?

```
cat RootCertificates | tr -d '*CN='  | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` instead.

```
sed 's/^.*CN=//' < RootCertificates | sort | ..
```

.. also, [try to avoid `cat` if you can](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). In this can you can redirect the input of `sed` from your file.

Comment: You don't need the `g` global flag by the way, the regex definition will only match the one thing by virtue of the `^` anchor. But good answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed to have `CN=` on every line, a simple `cut` would suffice and there is no need for a regex:

```
cut -f2 -d= RootCertificates | sort | uniq -c
```

For your file, the output is:

```
  2 Google Internet Authority G2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `grep`

```
  grep -o 'CN=.*' file | sort | uniq -c
  2 CN=Google Internet Authority G2
```

or if you don't want the `CN`using your input

```
cut -d "=" -f2 file | sort | uniq -c
2 Google Internet Authority G2
```